# preg_match lookbehind after second slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is my string:

```
stringa/stringb/123456789,abc,cde
```

and after preg_match:

```
preg_match('/(?<=\/).*?(?=,)/',$array,$matches);
```

output is:

```
stringb/123456789
```

How can I change my preg_match to extract the string after second slash (or after last slash)?

Desired output:

```
123456789
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match anything other than a `/` as

```
/(?<=\/)[^\/,]*(?=,)/
```

- `[^\/,]*` Negated character class matches anything other than `,` or `\`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uY4hV2/1)

**Example**

```
preg_match('/(?<=\/)[^\/,]*(?=,)/',$array,$matches);
// $matches[0]
// => 123456789
```

Comment: thank you, it works! shouldn't it be [...] other than `,` or `/` ?

Comment: @Driver Anything that is given in `[^ ]` will be negated. So to match anything other than `,` or `/` we should be giving it as `[^,\/]`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
<?php
$array = 'stringa/stringb/123456789,abc,cde';
preg_match('~.*/(.*?),~',$array,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
?>
```

Disregard everything until the last forward slash (`.*/`). Once the last forward slash is found keep all the data until the first comma(`(.*?),`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use lookbehind, i.e.:

```
$string = "stringa/stringb/123456789,abc,cde";
$string = preg_replace('%.*/(.*?),.*%', '$1', $string );
echo $string;
//123456789
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/IxdNbZ

---

Regex Explanation:

```
.*/(.*?),.*

Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “,” literally «,»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»

$1

Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
```